# Not able to set different log level for my particular package

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

I expected to turn off logging for the package by setting `level=OFF` for my package.
However, I am not able to do it and logs are still added in the log file.

I have tried to

```
<!-- <logger name="org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider" 
    level="OFF"/> -->
<logger name="LOG-INFO" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE-ERROR" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.spicemoney.BulkMessaging.Controller"
    level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE-ERROR" />
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">

</root>
```

Package is com.spicemoney.BulkMessaging.Controller.
But it is still in level INFO

[Here is the screeshot of package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9yXr.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from your package structure?

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy [https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9yXr.jpg] here the screenshot

Comment: Did you redeploy your project after changing the XML file?

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Yes I have redeployed it

Comment: Did you define anything related to logging in a properties file?

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy No, I did not

Comment: Are there any other loggers defined in your XML?

Comment: No, this is the only one